# How to show some pages only when someone login through OAuth in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, oauth-2.0, django-forms

I currently merged OAuth with one of my projects. What can I do, so that pages are not accessible for users who are not logged in?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Django oauth toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_02.html)? There is a ProtectedResourceView class just for that. If you also use django REST framework, you also can use permission classes and token scopes like [that](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-2-create-a-simple-api)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into them